# Extra whitespace character in output after each character, while reading the input line

Tags: python, python-2.7

When reading the input lines from stdin, there is extra whitespace character after each character in input.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in sys.stdin.readline():
        print line,
```

For example, while running the script, if I provide the input

```
This is the test input.
```

then output comes like

```
T h i s   i s   t h e   t e s t   i n p u t .
```

Can someone point out the reason for this behavior and how can I get the correct output?

Comment: You've mistaken `readline()` with `readlines()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you are looping on a string! readline() reads a single line and returns a string.

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    line = sys.stdin.readline();
    print line
```

Perhaps you wanted to read input line by line, you should use sys.stdin.readlines() which returns an array of strings. Then use:

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
        print line
```

This will work fine when you pipe input through a file. For typing input in through a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> twice in Linux (and <kbd>Ctrl+Z, Enter</kbd> in Windows) to send EOF from command line to stop input. Or you can modify your code to exit when something like "-1" is inputted.

Comment: Will it work when I have multi-line input? I am trying the read the multi-line input and when I do as you mentioned, it seems program keep on waiting and doesn't output anything.

Comment: Editing the answer for that. It waits for EOF(end of file) character